# Getting started with Keras for machine learning

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting started with machine learning tools and I'd like to learn more about what the heck I'm doing. For instance, the script:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, BatchNormalization
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(13)
RandomUniform(seed=13)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))

model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

data = numpy.loadtxt('train', delimiter=' ')
X = data[:, 0:6]
Y = data[:, 6]

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=1, epochs=1000)

data = numpy.loadtxt('test', delimiter=' ')
X = data[:, 0:6]
Y = data[:, 6]

score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=1)
print ('\n\nThe error is:\n', score, "\n")

print('\n\nPrediction:\n')
Y = model.predict(X, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
print('\nResult:\n', Y, '\n')
```

It's a Frankenstein I made from some examples I found on the internet and I have many unanswered questions about it:

1. The file *train* has 60 rows. Is 1000 epochs too little? Is it too much? Can I get an Underfit/Overfit?
2. What does the result I get from model.evaluate() mean? I know it's the loss but, if I get a [7.0506157875061035, 0.0], does it mean that my model has a 7% error?
3. And last, I'm getting a prediction of 0.99875391, 0.99875391, 0.9362126, 0.99875391, 0.99875391, 0.99875391, 0.93571019 when the expected values were anything close to 7.86, 3.57, 8.93, 6.57, 11.7, 8.53, 9.06, which means it's a real bad prediction. Clearly there's a lot of things I'm doing wrong. Could you guys give me a few pointers?

I know it all depends on the type of data I'm using, but is there anything I shouldn't do at all? Or maybe something I should be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1

There is never a ready answer for how many epochs is a good number. It varies wildly depending on the size of your data, your model, and what you want to achieve. Normally, small models require less epochs, bigger models require more. Yours seem small enough and 1000 epochs seems way too much.

It also depends on the `learning rate`, a parameter given to the optimizer that defines how long are the steps your model takes to update its weights. Bigger learning rates mean less epochs, but there is a chance that you simply never find a good point because you're adjusting weights beyond what is good. Smaller learning rates mean more epochs and better learning.

Normally, if the loss reaches a limit, you're approaching a point where training is not useful anymore. (Of course, there may be problems with the model too, there is really no simple answer for this one).

To detect overfitting, you need besides the training data (X and Y), another group with test data (say Xtest and Ytest, for instance).

Then you use it in `model.fit(X,Y, validation_data=(Xtest,Ytest), ...)`

Test data is not given for training, it's kept separate just to see if your model can predict good things from data it has never seen in training.

If the training loss goes down, but the validation loss doesn't, you're overfitting (roughly, your model is capable of memorizing the training data without really understanding it).

An underfit, on the contrary, happens when you never achieve the `accuracy` you expect (of course we always expect a 100% accuracy, no mistakes, but good models get around the 90's, some applicatoins go better 99%, some worse, again, it's very subjective).

## 2

`model.evaluate()` gives you the losses and the metrics you added in the `compile method`.

The loss value is something your model will always try to decrease during training. It roughly means how distant your model is from the exact values. There is no rule for what the loss value means, it could even be negative (but usually keras uses positive losses). The point is: it must decrease during training, that means your model is evolving.

The accuracy value means how many right predictions your model outputs compared to the true values (Y). It seems your accuracy is 0%, your model is getting everything wrong. (You can see that from the values you typed).

## 3

In your model, you used `activation functions`. These normalize the results so they don't get too big. This avoids overflowing problems, numeric errors propagating, etc.

It's very very usual to work with values within such bounds.

- `tanh` - outputs values between -1 and 1
- `sigmoid` - outputs values between 0 and 1

Well, if you used a sigmoid activation in the last layer, your model will never output 3 for instance. It tries, but the maximum value is 1.

What you should do is prepare your data (Y), so it's contained between 0 and 1. (This is the best to do in classification problems, often done with images too)

But if you actually want numerical values, then you should just remove the activation and let the output be free to reach higher values.  (It all depends on what you want to achieve with your model)

Comment: Your answers really helped me understand a little better how these things work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Epoch is a single pass through the full training set. I my mind it seems a lot, but you'd have to check for overfitting and evaluate the predictions. There are many ways of checking and controlling for overfitting in a model. If you understand the methods of doing so from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html#model-selection), coding them in Keras should be no problem.
2. According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) `.evaluate` returns:

> Scalar test loss (if the model has no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model computes other metrics)

so these are the evaluation metrics of your model, they tell you how good your model is given some notion of good. Those metrics depend on the model and type of data that you've used. Some explanation on those can be found [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/7-important-model-evaluation-error-metrics/) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). As mentioned in the documentation,

> The attribute  model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs.

So you can know what metric you are looking at. It is easier to do that interactively through the console (ipython, bpython) or Jupyter notebook.

3. I can't see your data, but a if you are doing a classification problem as suggested by `metrics=['accuracy']`, the `loss=mean_absolute_error` doesn't make sense, since it is made for regression problems. To learn more about those I refer you to [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/) and [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) which discuss classification and regression problems with Keras.

PS: question 3 is not related to software per se, but to the theoretical construct supporting the software. In such cases, I'd recommend asking them at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, Guilherme. Those links you sent me look like a good starting point. I'll definitely check'em all out to try and get better at this. Thank you again.